# Unable to run convert command in CentOS using (ImageMagick)

Tags: imagemagick, centos5

I am new to ImageMagick and I am simply trying to run convert command at Command line which is as follows:

```
convert '/home/674390/Desktop/rose.jpg' '/home/674390/Desktop/rose.png'
```

Getting an error message:

> convert: unable to open image `/home/674390/Desktop/rose.jpg': No such
>   file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643. convert: no decode
>   delegate for this image format`/home/674390/Desktop/rose.jpg' @
>   error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555. convert: no images defined
>   `/home/674390/Desktop/rose.png' @
>   error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3144.

Please help.

My Operating System is CentOS.

Comment: Try without the quotes: `convert /home/674390/Desktop/rose.jpg /home/674390/Desktop/rose.png` do you still get the same error?

Comment: yes Andrea... error still persists.........:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's three errors involved with your convert command.

> convert: unable to open image /home/674390/Desktop/rose.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643.

This means exactly what it says. There is no file at that path, or you do not have read permissions to access it.

> convert: no decode delegate for this image format/home/674390/Desktop/rose.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/555.

This message is informing you that you'll need to install `libjpeg` to work with this file format. See [ImageMagick Delegates](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/) for resources. You can also verify what your system can work with by running the following commands.

```sh
convert -list delegate | less
convert -list format | less
```

Finally

> convert: no images defined `/home/674390/Desktop/rose.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3144.

As the first image could not be opened, `convert` now believes the distention file is the source file, and attempts to open it for reading. And so, a message identical to the first one is displayed.

Comment: i just executed

identify -list format and i don't find any .jpeg/.png but when i excecuted the same file in .gif format it worked & it converted to png,jpeg format

but my file didn't open up :(

any suggestions?????